# API managing events (create/update) using .ics format in JAVA

Tags: java, icalendar

I'm looking for an open source `API` allowing to manage `events` in `Java`. My needs are to create `.ics file` that contains one (or many) event(s) in order to synchronise them.

Also it will be very helpfull if this API can manage update (ie : if we can update event that we first create with the same system).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used ical4j (https://code.google.com/p/ical4j/) for similar problems some months ago.

This should give you a good start to solve your problem.